# Help on a Hilbert Space theory utilization.

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I need some help here concerning the Hilbert Spaces theory. Below, you can see a part of **Olivier Chapelle's** paper: *"Training a Support Vector Machine in the Primal"*. As you can see below, in Eq.(8) the optimization problem is stated in its primal form, while using a kernel $\mathcal{k}$ and an associated RKHS $\mathcal{H}$, the author ends in Eq.(9).

Why does it happen? What would be the form of Eq.(9) if the bias term $b$ was not zero?

Any comment would be very useful,
Thanks in advance!

[image]